# How to add Parent node in existing XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

My program is using vb.net language , here is my xml

```
<Result>
 <ID>1</ID>
<VERSION_NO>1.0.0.1</VERSION_NO>
<TIME>1</TIME>
</Result>
```

How to add parent node is this xml like this

```
<Result>
 <ID>1</ID>
<VERSION_NO>1.0.0.1</VERSION_NO>
<TIME>1</TIME>
</Result>
<Result>
 <ID>2</ID>
<VERSION_NO>1.0.0.2</VERSION_NO>
<TIME>5</TIME>
</Result>
<Result>
 <ID>3</ID>
<VERSION_NO>1.0.0.3</VERSION_NO>
<TIME>5</TIME>
</Result>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is that the *entire* XML document (excluding the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top)? Because if so, what you're asking for can't be directly done - each XML document has to have precisely *one* root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.xml"
    'Create the original file'
    Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
    xdc.AppendChild(xdc.CreateElement("Results")) 'This is the document node that contains all other nodes'
    xdc.FirstChild.AppendChild(NewResult(xdc, "1", "1.0.0.1", "1"))
    xdc.Save(strFilename) 'save the file with only one Result node'
    xdc = Nothing
    'now load the file and add two more nodes'
    Dim xdc2 As New XmlDocument
    xdc2.Load(strFilename)
    xdc2.FirstChild.AppendChild(NewResult(xdc2, "2", "1.0.0.2", "5"))
    xdc2.FirstChild.AppendChild(NewResult(xdc2, "3", "1.0.0.3", "5"))
    xdc2.Save(strFilename) 'save the file with the new nodes added'
    xdc2 = Nothing
    'now display the file'
    Dim s As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(strFilename)
    MsgBox(s)
  End Sub

  Private Shared Function NewResult(xdc As XmlDocument, id As String, versionNo As String, time As String) As XmlNode
    Dim xndResult As XmlNode = xdc.CreateElement("Result")

    Dim xndID As XmlNode = xdc.CreateElement("ID")
    xndID.AppendChild(xdc.CreateTextNode(id))
    xndResult.AppendChild(xndID)

    Dim xndVersionNo As XmlNode = xdc.CreateElement("VERSION_NO")
    xndVersionNo.AppendChild(xdc.CreateTextNode(versionNo))
    xndResult.AppendChild(xndVersionNo)

    Dim xndTime As XmlNode = xdc.CreateElement("TIME")
    xndTime.AppendChild(xdc.CreateTextNode(time))
    xndResult.AppendChild(xndTime)

    Return xndResult
  End Function
End Class
```